# Keras Custom Layer Working with Constants and Variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i have some problems with Keras custom layer and lambda layers/function. I will be glad if somebody can help.

I try to build a custom layer to make some calculations and save/reuse old values in a variable. Keras-Documentation advises to use subclasses indeed lamda functions if you work with variables.

```
# Define Constante outside of the Model

c = tf.constant(5., dtype=tf.float32)

# Define Custom Layer

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()
        self.prev_input = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(input_dim),
                                      trainable=False)
        self.prev_output = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(input_dim),
                                       trainable=False)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "prev_input": self.prev_input,
            "prev_output": self.prev_output,
        })
        return config

    def call(self, inputs_, training=False):
        a = inputs_[0]
        b = inputs_[1]
        t = K.get_value(c)
        output = self.prev_output*a*b / t 
        self.prev_input = inputs_
        self.prev_output = output
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return tf.TensorShape([None, 1])
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry. I get by fiting the model error messages about the MyLayer. Im not sure if i can access to the constant c in the layer too. 
this is the error if i try to save the model in h5 file: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

and the pycharm says that the object is not callable. i add the layer directly to the model in Functional mode and seems okay in model.summary. 
Thank you

Comment: Please explain your issue end to end. Also why do you need to access a constant outside of your layer?